# Input three Numbers and determine the highest and lowest numbers in c++

Tags: c++

I'm beginner in Programming and in C++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double a, b, c;

    cout << "Enter the First number: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Enter the Second number: ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Enter the Third Number: ";
    cin >> c;

    if (a > b && a > c)
    {
        cout << "The Highest Number is: " << a << endl;
    }
    else if (b > a && b > c)
    {
        cout << "The Highest Number is: " << b << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The Highest Number is: " << c << endl; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see I have the program for getting the Highest number, the problems is I can't get the best solution for getting the lowest number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easy way to find MAX/MIN in any set of numbers (array).
just run through all the numbers, and if you find a "lower" than current minimum, you found a new minimum.
when all numbers are traversed, you know you have the absolute minimum.

Question: what should i set the current_minimum to at the first place?
Answer: Either, the maximum possible value, or the first element.

code as:

```
int min, max;
max = min = array[0];
for(int i=1; i<array_length; ++i)
{
  if(array[i] > max) max = array[i];
  if(array[i] < min) min = array[i];
}
```

it is easily unfolded for specifically 3 numbers as shown:

```
int min, max;
max = min = a;
if(b > max) max = b;
else if(b < mid) min = b;
if(c > max) max = c;
else if(c < min) min = c;
cout << "minimum is : " << min << endl;
cout << "maximum is : " << max << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::max` and `std::min` functions defined in `algorithm`header file.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a,b,c;
    std::cin>>a>>b>>c;
    std::cout<<std::max(a,std::max(b,c))<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<std::min(a,std::min(b,c))<<std::endl;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to do this: If a > b and a > c and b > c : "c is the lowest number" you just need to compare the two lowest in the previous definition. By doing that tou are comparaing all the numbers, and putting 'c' like the lowest

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int a,b,c;
cout<<"TYPE ANY THREE NUMBER: ";
  cin>>a>>b>>c;
  if (a>b)
  { 
 if (a>c)
    { 
      cout<<"THE MAXIMUM NO IS: "<<a<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
      cout<<"THE MAXIMUM NO IS: "<<c<<endl;
    }
     }
  if (b>c)
  {
    cout<<"THE MAXIMUM NO IS: "<<b<<endl;
  }
  else
  {
    cout<<"THE MAXIMUM NO IS: "<<c<<endl;
  }
 {
    cout<<"THE MAXIMUM NO IS: "<<min(a,min(b,c))<<endl;
  }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: add some description to the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num1,num2,num3;  //declare the variables

    cout << "Enter the first number: ";
    cin>>num1;//get input from user for num1
    cout << "Enter the second number: ";
    cin>>num2;//get input from user for num2
    cout << "Enter the third number: ";
    cin>>num3;//get input from user for num3

    cout<<"\n\nThe biggest number is: ";
    if((num1>num2)&&(num1>num3)){
        cout<<num1;
    }
    else if(num2>num3){
       cout<<num2;
    }
    else{
        cout<<num3;
    }

    cout<<"\n\nThe smallest number is: ";
    if((num1<num2)&&(num1<num3)){
        cout<<num1;
    }
    else if(num2<num3){
        cout<<num2;
    }
    else{
        cout<<num3;
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my answer which was accepted in the`codeforces`paltform algorithms:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long a, b, c, min, max;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    smallest = a;
    largest = b;
    if (b < min)
    {
        min = b;
    }

    if (c < min)
    {
        min = c;
    }
    if (c > max)
    {
        max = c;
    }

    if (a > max)
    {
        max = a;
    }
    cout<<min<<" "<<max<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```